# 2 PSU for 2 GPUs

Tags: mining, power-consumption

First is old Fortron 500w, working perfect but can't handle 2gpus. Second PSU is even older noname(Mercury) 350w.

Second GPU is powered trought riser purely with 350w PSU.

Apart from power consumption, is there any dissatwantage of such a setup ?

Both PSUs are grounded together and my rig is running smoothly for 5 days already. No over heating on PSUs

Thank you for giving me peace for my mind :)